# JSON format not recognised using Amazon Java SDK

Tags: java, json, coldfusion

I am using the Amazon Pay SDK with Coldfusion and I have nearly got it over the line. However, I am trying to use the updateCheckoutSession method and it doesn't recognize the arguments for that method. When I call the method I get the following error:

[image]

I have tried creating and formatting the JSON as many different ways as I can think of and I just keep getting the same error (error above).

My call to the method:

```
<!-- Gets the Session ID from the URL -->
<cfset amzSessionId = url.amazonCheckoutSessionId>          
<cfobject action="create" type="java" class="com.amazon.pay.api.WebstoreClient" name="WebstoreClient">
<cfset theJson = '{"webCheckoutDetails":{"checkoutResultReturnUrl":"XXXXXX"},"paymentDetails":{"paymentIntent":"AuthorizeWithCapture","canHandlePendingAuthorization":false,"softDescriptor":"Descriptor","chargeAmount":{"amount":"#orderTotal#","currencyCode":"GBP"}},"merchantMetadata":{"merchantReferenceId":"XXXXXX","merchantStoreName":"XXXXXX"}}'>
<cfset updateResponse = WebstoreClient.updateCheckoutSession(amzSessionId,theJson)>
```

Below is a CFDUMP of the WebstoreClient and the update method is shown at the bottom.

[image]

If you need any additional information I will be glad to provide it.

Comment: Try a `cfdump` of WebstoreClient to verify that the method exists.

Comment: Hi Dan, I had already checked this, but I have edited the question and pasted the dump from the WebstoreClient, just in case you spot something I didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are supposed to pass a java [`JSONObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) type variable [refer](https://github.com/amzn/amazon-pay-api-sdk-java/blob/7135fcd4e0826dffdc29ddffdd17bb6bfefb4cde/src/com/amazon/pay/api/WebstoreClient.java#L125). So the following should theoretically work.

```
<cfset theJsonString = '{"webCheckoutDetails":{"checkoutResultReturnUrl":"XXXXXX"},"paymentDetails":{"paymentIntent":"AuthorizeWithCapture","canHandlePendingAuthorization":false,"softDescriptor":"Descriptor","chargeAmount":{"amount":"#orderTotal#","currencyCode":"GBP"}},"merchantMetadata":{"merchantReferenceId":"XXXXXX","merchantStoreName":"XXXXXX"}}'>
<cfset theJsonObject = createObject('java', 'org.json.JSONObject').init(theJsonString)>
<cfset updateResponse = WebstoreClient.updateCheckoutSession(amzSessionId, theJsonObject)>
```

Comment: That's great, thanks for your help. I didn't realize there was a difference between a JSON string and a JSON object, I thought they were the same thing. I will definitely remember this for the future, as I was losing my mind over this lol.